# How to automatically get new google refresh token in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I'm making a plugin that sends mail in trapi cms using nodemailer and google's oauth2, however my tokens automatically expire after 1 hour. I am trying several ways but my code still not working. Here is my code:

```js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  `"${process.env.CLIENT_ID }"`,
  `"${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}"`,
  "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground",
  
);

// oauth2Client.setCredentials({
//   refresh_token: `"${process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN }"`,
// });
// const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken()

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  
  // ...
  email: {
    
    provider: env(`${process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_PROVIDER}`),
    providerOptions: {
      host: env("EMAIL_SMTP_HOST", "smtp.gmail.com"),
      port: env("EMAIL_SMTP_PORT", 587),
      auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: "hotrodhv58@gmail.com",
        clientId: `"${process.env.CLIENT_ID }"`,
        clientSecret: `"${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}"`,
        refreshToken: `"${process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN}"`,
        accessToken:  `"${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}"`,
      },
    },
    settings: {
      defaultFrom: env(`${process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FROM}`),
      defaultReplyTo: env(`${process.env.REACT_APP_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REPLY}`),
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

The error I received:

> Error sending email to xxxxssss@gmail.com {"code":"EAUTH","command":"AUTH XOAUTH2"}

If I leave Async Await in the module, I will receive an error:

> {"Errno":-4078, "code": "Esocket", "Syncall": "Connect", "Address":"127.0.0.1", "Port": 587, "Command": "Conn"}}

What do I need to do to make them work. Hope to get help from everyone!

Comment: does `new OAuth2` actually expect its argument to contain `"` - I get the feeling if you remove all the `""` inside `\`\`` you'll get a better result - e.g. instead of `\`"${process.env.CLIENT_ID }"\`` it's `\`${process.env.CLIENT_ID }\``

Comment: I have tried, but now I have a new problem which I am not able to get the access token that is set at const accessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken(), and get error missing value for oauth2

Comment: can you post the EXACT error

Comment: @JaromandaX I've edited

Comment: `Connect", "Address":"127.0.0.1"` looks wrong

Comment: @Jaromanda I have logged out accesstoken but it returns [object] [object] maybe the function to create new codes is not working

Comment: is it `[object] [object]` or `[object Object]` ? the former suggests you're logging two things that have the value `"[object]"` - the latter suggests you're logging an actual object, and coercing the output to a string, therefore you get the `[object Object]` - my guess is it's the latter and you are logging a *Promise*

Comment: Yes as you said! I have JSON.stringify(accessToken) and now my token is in {data:{access_token: xxx}} so how do i get the token

Comment: It's there.  accessToken ... you don't need to stringify it. You have it

Comment: Can i ask more, why when i remove async await in export module, it gives this error Error sending email to trungsoobin10@gmail.com {"errno":-4078,"code":"ESOCKET"," syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":587,"command":"CONN"}